# Why it is not possible to overload compound assignment operator in C#?

Tags: c#, language-design, operators

*The title is be misleading, so please read entire question :-)*.

By "compound assignment operator" I have in mind a construct like this `op=`, for example `+=`. Pure assignment operator (`=`) does not belong to my question.

By "why" I don't mean an opinion, but resource (book, article, etc) when some of the designers, or their coworkers, etc. express their **reasoning** (i.e. the source of the design choice).

I am puzzled by asymmetry found in C++ and C# (*yes, I know C# is not C++ 2.0*) -- in C++ you would overload operator `+=` and then almost automatically write appropriate `+` operator relying on previously defined operator. In C# it is in reverse -- you overload `+` and `+=` is synthesised for you.

If I am not mistaken the later approach kills a chance for optimization in case of actual `+=`, because new object has to be created. So there has to be some big advantage of such approach, but MSDN is too shy to tell about it.

And I wonder what that advantage is -- so if you spotted explanation in some C# book, tech-talk video, blog entry, I will be grateful for the reference.

*The closest thing I found is a comment on Eric Lippert blog [Why are overloaded operators always static in C#?](https://ericlippert.com/2007/05/14/why-are-overloaded-operators-always-static-in-c/) by Tom Brown. If the static overloading was decided first it simply dictates which operators can be overloaded for structs. This further dictates what can be overloaded for classes.*

Comment: Do you have a link for the new C++ style? Naively, overloading `+=` first seems absurd; why would you overload a combined operation rather than the parts of it?

Comment: @Telastyn, no (it is pretty old), but excluding some commutative problems, you would usually go with pattern "define one, get others for free". So you usually define pre-increment operator, less operator and op-assignment operators, and the rest is built upon those. I don't want to deal with this topic further, so as an example make an experiment, define `*` and then `*=` for a 1000x1000 matrix, where RHS parameter is `float`. And then reverse dependency of those operators.

Comment: I believe the term for these is "compound assignment operators".

Comment: @greenoldman Telastyn was probably implying that implementing += in terms of + seems more natural than the other way around, since semantically += is a composition of + and =. [To the best of my knowledge](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/), having + call += is largely an optimization trick.

Comment: @Ixrec, thank you very much for fixing my terminology :-). Also thank you for noticing the natural flow, with defining `+=` first there is some nasty side-effect in reference world, that `X op= Y` is no longer a shortcut to `X = X op Y`. And I am frightened that this optimization is not worth destroying this notion (I am designing my own language).

Comment: @Ixrec: Sometimes, a+=b makes sense, while a=a+b doesn't: Consider that identity might be important, an A cannot be duplicated, whatever. Sometimes, a=a+b makes sense, while a+=b doesn't: Consider immutable strings. So, one actually needs the ability to decide which one to overload separately. Of course, auto-generating the missing one, if all neccessary building-blocks exist and it's not explicitly disables, is a good idea. Not that C# allows that atm, afaik.

Comment: @greenoldman Ideally, the innards of C# are smart enough to perform that optimization when automagically writing the += operator. I'm not a C# guy so I have no idea if they are. Perhaps we should ask Jon Skeet about that.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agreed. I was only responding to the issue of having + call += versus += calling +, on the assumption that you already needed/wanted to implement both operators.

Comment: Eric Lippert would probably point out that any feature is unsupported until somebody decides to support it. So for any supported feature there is some reasoning behind it, but for unsupported features they might not necessarily be a design choice behind the lack of support. Perhaps nobody thought of including it?

Comment: @greenoldman - I understand that motivation, but personally, I would find `*=` mutating a reference type to be semantically incorrect.

Comment: @Telastyn, I am afraid of that too :-).

Comment: @Deduplicator How in the *world* does a+=b not make sense with immutable strings? I would expect it to concatenate then and assign the new result to the variable. I would *always* expect that a `+` operator generates a new object instead of modifying one in place; doing anything else is just poor design. As for preserving identity with a+=b, you could use an internal cache (similar to string interning) to fetch an existing value during `+`, thus preventing duplication. The semantics of += make *no* sense unless the semantics of + make sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't find the reference for this, but my understanding was that the C# team wanted to provide a sane subset of operator overloading. At the time, operator overloading had a bad rap. People asserted that it obfuscated code, and could only be used for evil. By the time C# was being designed, Java had shown us that *no* operator overloading was kind of annoying.

So C# wanted to balance operator overloading so that it was more difficult to do evil, but you could make nice things too. Changing the semantics of assignment was one of those things that was deemed always evil. By allowing `+=` and its kin to be overloaded, it would allow that sort of thing. For example, if `+=` mutated the reference rather than making a new one, it wouldn't follow the expected semantics, leading to bugs.

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mind I will keep this question open bit longer, and if nobody beat you with the reasoning of actual design, I will close it with accepting yours. Once again -- thank you.

Comment: @greenoldman - as well you should. I too hope someone come with a answer with more concrete references.

Comment: So, this is a place where the impossibility of talking both about the pointer and the pointee comfortably and unambiguously rears it's head? Damn shame.

Comment: "People asserted that it obfuscated code" - it's still true though, have you seen some of the F# libraries? Operator noise. E.g. http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec